# Calculating the percentage of the difference between two values

Tags: calculator

If I have the following two different values for x:

x = 0.022

x = 0.020

And, if I want to calculate the *percentage* of the difference (change) in x, will it be?

---> 0.022 - 0.020 = 0.002

---> 0.002 x 100% = 0.2%?

And, should the percentage of the difference be always positive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you have an initial value for $x$, and then a later value for $x$, and you want to calculate what percent change you have from the initial value of $x$.

So say you have two values $x_1=.02$ and $x_2=.022$. So as you've calculated, the increase in going from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is $.022-.02=.002$. But $.002/.02=.1$, so there has been a $10\%$ increase in $x$ from the initial value.

The percentage of the difference won't always be positive if your second value of $x$ is smaller than the first. For example, if instead $x_1=.022$ and $x_2=.02$, then the change is $-.002/.022\approx-9.09\%$.

In general, to find the percentage of change, you can use the formula
$$
\frac{x_f-x_i}{x_i}\cdot 100\%
$$
where $x_i$ is your initial value of $x$, and $x_f$ is your final value of $x$.

Comment: Does this work for negative numbers?  What if your initial is -10 and your final is -5?

Comment: You can use the formula and find that -10 reduced by 50% is -5.  I'm not sure many people would see it that way because they just don't like negative numbers.  But if you were in debt by $10 and paid off 5, you would have reduced your debt by 50%, right?

Comment: The percent difference of -10 to -5 is an INCREASE of 50% since you are going from a smaller to a larger number.

Comment: The formula should always include the Absolute Value of the Denominator!